# Are we allowed to bring many small containers of liquids on the plane?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security

Can we take 10 different liquids: creams, toothpaste, and such, each below 100 ml on the plane? They total 480 g.

what is the general rule?

Comment: You will need to add your location, as rules are not the same world wide. But in many countries the rules are alike those of the TSA, in the USA. Like those in this question for the EU: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116216/getting-the-bag-and-100ml-containers-for-flying-with-liquids-in-hand-luggage

Comment: Some things to keep in mind, for most countries: the container must be 100ml or smaller.  A 200 ml container is not acceptable, even if it is clearly less than half full.  All containers must be inside a 1-liter sealable plastic bag, and there may be no more than 1 such bag for each person in your party.  So it sounds like you can probably do this, provided that all of the containers are 100 ml or smaller.

Comment: Technically, and according to the TSA website, toothpaste is _not_ a liquid. But you never know what the TSA guy that checks you thinks, and he makes the rule in that moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US you can bring them if all of them fit in a single quart sized zip lock bag.  One quart is a little less than one liter, so 480 gr may fit depending on size and shape of the containers.

Europe is basically the same but with 1 liter bag instead of a quart (minor difference).

Sources

- [https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/what-3-1-1-liquids-rule#:~:text=Each%20passenger%20may%20carry%20liquids,of%20liquids%2C%20gels%20and%20aerosols](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/what-3-1-1-liquids-rule#:%7E:text=Each%20passenger%20may%20carry%20liquids,of%20liquids%2C%20gels%20and%20aerosols).
- https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/luggage-restrictions/index_en.htm

Comment: Note that (in the US, at least) each container must be 100 ml or smaller.  A larger container is unacceptable even if the quantity of liquid inside is clearly smaller than 100 ml.  Also, I've never encountered a TSA officer who paid enough attention to the size of the bag to come anywhere close to rejecting a 1-liter bag as too large.